# How can I get records based on month and year from table?

Tags: mysql, sql

Can we use just month and year part of date in a where clause for to filter date field?

```
    SELECT `outlet`.`outlet`,cities.`city`,teritory.`teritory`,region.`region`,`countries`.`country` FROM `audit`
    JOIN `user` ON `user`.`id`=`audit`.`auditor_id`
    JOIN `user_outlet` ON `user_outlet`.id=`audit`.`outlet_id`
    JOIN `outlet` ON `outlet`.id=`user_outlet`.`outlet_id`
    JOIN `cities` ON `cities`.`id`=`outlet`.`city_id`
    JOIN `teritory_city` ON `teritory_city`.`city_id`=`cities`.id
    JOIN `teritory` ON `teritory_city`.`teritory_id`=`teritory`.`id`
    JOIN `region` ON `region`.`id`=`teritory`.`region_id`
    JOIN `org_country` ON `org_country`.`id`=`region`.`org_country_id`
    JOIN `countries` ON `countries`.`id`=`org_country`.`country_id`
    WHERE `audit`.`created_date`=?
```

Above is the query which I Tried , I have to pass year and month parameters instead of passing date.
In UI Year and months are the only filters I am providing to the user to fetch respective data in that particular month and year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `year()` and `month()` function like below-

```
SELECT `outlet`.`outlet`,cities.`city`,teritory.`teritory`,region.`region`,`countries`.`country` FROM `audit`
JOIN `user` ON `user`.`id`=`audit`.`auditor_id`
JOIN `user_outlet` ON `user_outlet`.id=`audit`.`outlet_id`
JOIN `outlet` ON `outlet`.id=`user_outlet`.`outlet_id`
JOIN `cities` ON `cities`.`id`=`outlet`.`city_id`
JOIN `teritory_city` ON `teritory_city`.`city_id`=`cities`.id
JOIN `teritory` ON `teritory_city`.`teritory_id`=`teritory`.`id`
JOIN `region` ON `region`.`id`=`teritory`.`region_id`
JOIN `org_country` ON `org_country`.`id`=`region`.`org_country_id`
JOIN `countries` ON `countries`.`id`=`org_country`.`country_id`
WHERE year(`audit`.`created_date`)=yearparam and month(`audit`.`created_date`)=monthparam
```

Comment: To get any sort of index performance `WHERE audit.created_date >= YYYY-MM-01 AND audit.created_date < YYYY-(MM+1)-01`. Is the output meant to be distinct in any way?

Answer (score 0):

Try to avoid using functions on columns in `WHERE` clauses.  This can prevent the optimizer from choosing the best optimization plan.

I would suggest:

```
where audit.created_date >= date(concat_ws('-', @yearparam, @monthparam, 1) and
      audit.created_date < date(concat_ws('-', @yearparam, @monthparam, 1) + interval 1 month
```